# Using Update() results in LateUpdate()

Tags: unity-game-engine

I understand in `LateUpdate()` I already have the results of `Update()` so I can make further changes to those results and then the rendering/animation will reflect these latest changes, but why then can I not call the `currentPose` and `targetModel` variables in `LateUpdate()` below? How do I refer to their latest values?

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3[] latestPositions;
    Quaternion[] latestOrientations;

    // Get the pose data in one call.
    if (Actors.getLatestPose(actorID, out latestPositions, out latestOrientations))
    {
        // Update both the pose and the model.
        updateActor(currentPose, latestPositions, latestOrientations);
        updateModel(currentPose, targetModel);
    }
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    updateMimicLimb();
}
```

Comment: You can call but probably you are having issue in your if statement in Update function. can you send your updateMiniclimb method too. And is it working when you call updateMiniclimb() method after updateModel().

Comment: You can save currentPose and targetModel to global vars in Update method, and then take it in LateUpdate method

Comment: @Suvitruf Do you mean within the `if` statement and immediately after `updateModel(currentPose, targetModel);` I should do: `CurrentPose =  currentPose; TargetModel = targetModel` Is this what you mean? What keyword should preceed the variables to make them `global` within the `if` statement? `static`?

Comment: @burak Karasoy Thank you. I am still working on `updateMimicLimb` because I need the latest results of `currentPose` and `targetModel` but I will add it in an EDIT as soon as I have its definition. How do you suggest I save the latest `currentPose` and `targetModel` to be accessible in `LateUpdate`?

Comment: `currentPose` and `targetModel` are declared as `private` class variables already. So, do you mean I should make them `private static` in order to be able to use them in `LateUpdate`?